# Question about the decision between normal and lognormal distribution in a linear model

Tags: normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, lognormal-distribution

I hope someone could help me with the following problem:
If I create a linear model that predicts the height of people (y) with the following parameters:

y = a + b*(xi-xavg)

with "a" the normally distributed (178,20) the prior distribution of heights and "b" a coefficient for the effect of the weight on the height prediction. The question is if I have to choose the normal distribution or the lognormal distribution for coefficient "b". I understand that the normal distribution has the maximum entropy for a given variance (sigma = Uniform(0,50) here) so do I just pick the normal distribution here?

Comment: FWIW the lognormal is the maximum entropy distribution with a specified *geometric* mean and variance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Distributions_with_measured_constants , so that principle doesn't help you decide ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb:

*Normal* models an **additive** product, *LogNormal* is a **multiplicative** product of many 'weak' influences.

*Normal* **can be negative**, *LogNormal* is strictly **non-negative**.

The first point doesn't really matter in this case. As for the second, if you used LogNormal without any additional processing, you're assuming the weight can only influence the height *positively*, which seems like an ungrounded and unnecessary assumption.

For example. you could argue that people with a lithe build tend to be taller, and that the impact of the added height is overshadowed by the impact of the body type.